# Poppler 0.14.1 build issue

Tags: linux, poppler

I cannot build Poppler 0.14.1 from source code on CentOS 5.4. When I do ./configure it ends with a message like:

> checking for FONTCONFIG... configure:
>   error: Package requirements
>   (fontconfig >= 2.0.0) were not met:

I have successfully built from source code, and installed

> fontconfig 2.8.0

on that machine, and also set the PKG_CONFIG to point to the folder that contains the fontconfig.pc (/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/).

It is true that when I do $PKG_CONFIG --version fontconfig it gets echos '0.20' but the fontconfig.pc does write that the version of the library is 2.8.0. Also there are no other libfontconfig.so other then the one build from source on that machine, so I am sort of stuck and not sure what to do (except debugging configure)

Has anyone solved a similar case before?
Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if the package fontconfig-devel is installed. If not, install it and then try your build again.

Comment: In 2015 the package for ubuntu 14.04 is called libfontconfig1-dev

Answer (score 0):

For debian squezee, I've had to install packages manually from the sources:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/

(Download directly, not use the git because there are problems when configure)

And BTW, very useful guide to install poopler and dependences from the scratch:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/poppler.html